# How to get the result of SELECT statement inside a transaction?

Tags: postgresql, transactions

I can't get information of that simple question over the PostgreSQL documentation, over the Web or even here on StackOverflow... I must not understand something essential here.

I am making a simple `SELECT`/`UPDATE` transaction in PostgreSQL:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT "column" FROM "table" WHERE "criterion" = 'value' AND "activated" = true;
UPDATE "table" SET "activated" = false WHERE "criterion" = 'value';
COMMIT
```

Basically, I need to get the value of a column when its `activated` state is `true` and then deactivate it.
PostgreSQL tells me that there was a 1 row result that has been cancelled

The same happens if I do the following (basically the same transaction without the `UPDATE` statement):

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT "column" FROM "table" WHERE "criterion" = 'value' AND "activated" = true;
COMMIT
```

What don't I understand about transactions? Can't any `SELECT` output get out of a transaction block?

Comment: You'd usually `SELECT "column", the_primary_ky FROM ...` then `UPDATE ... SET ... WHERE the_primary_key = value_returned_from_select`.

Comment: It depends on what you intend to do. Not that case here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return all "column"'s values from the updated rows:

```
UPDATE "table" SET "activated" = false WHERE "criterion" = 'value' AND "activated" = true
returning "column";
```

There is no relation to the transaction.

`returning` will return the values as if a `select` was issued:

```
insert into foo (ticket, row, archived) values (3,7,true) returning *;
 ticket | row | archived 
--------+-----+----------
      3 |   7 | t
```

---

```
update foo
set archived = true
where not archived
returning *;
 ticket | row | archived 
--------+-----+----------
      2 |   5 | t
```

Comment: If the transaction has no impact, how do you explain the second one? A simple `SELECT` wrapped in a transaction hides its result...

I am not using PL/pgSQL, RETURNING doesn't work here. Never saw that command before

Comment: @user573152 It will return as if it was a `select`. See the edited post. _how do you explain the second one_ Second one what?

Comment: I provided 2 transactions in my post, none of them working. The 2nd one is a simple `SELECT` in a transaction. That's useless that way, but that should still workm shouldn't it?

Oh and I finally got it working using the `RETURNING` statement. Thanks!