# How get select result fron transaction block?

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions

I have query. And I'm need get value of select in bottom query. But I can't do after commit transactions. How I can get it?

```
start transaction;

with table  as
(
       select id, type, status 
       from new_rows
       where status = 'new'

),     
       insert_table as
(
       insert into copy_table(type, status)
       select type, status  
       from table
       returning id, type
),
       del_table as
(
       delete
       from new_rows
       where id in (select id from table)
       returning id, type
)

select 'insert', *
from insert_table
union
select 'delete', *
from del_table
order by 2;

commit transaction;
```

I ready many question on stackoverflow (I think this one was the most suitable, but I could not apply this solution in my situation [How to get the result of SELECT statement inside a transaction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058790/how-to-get-the-result-of-select-statement-inside-a-transaction)), an try read postgres documentation, иге I don't find anwer on my question. I would be grateful for any information, please

Comment: Create a temporary table with the result, that will survive the end of the transaction.

Comment: the difficulty is that I make a request on a remote server and want to pick up the result in order to apply it on the local server

Comment: I don't see why that would make a difference. The result from `SELECT * FROM temptable;` run after the commit will be just as good as the result from your statement.

Comment: I cant create temptable on remote server

Comment: That's silly. Then tell the DBA to give you the `TEMP` privilege on the database.

Comment: if it were possible, I would have done so long ago. But this is not possible, which is why I asked this question.Please don't change the subject

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Did I understand you correctly that there is no other option?

Comment: There are probably 100 other options, this is just the first that occurred to me.

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas:

- Store the result in a temporary table and return its contents after commit.
- Store the result of the query in a `jsonb` variable (use `to_jsonb` and `jsonb_agg`) and extract the result after the commit.